# Unable to access items in c# array (For cs:go trading bot)

Tags: c#, arrays, list

im reprogramming the tf2 tradebot by JesseCar 96 for CS:go. Im trying to get the items stored in a list array and I can't figure out how to access it. The instantiation and item data works like this:

```
    public class TradeUserAssets : IEquatable<TradeUserAssets>, IComparable<TradeUserAssets>
{
    /// <summary>Inventory type</summary>
    public long contextid { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>itemid</summary>
    public ulong assetid { get; private set; }
    public int appid { get; private set; }
    public int amount { get; private set; }

    public TradeUserAssets(int appid, long contextid, ulong assetid, int amount = 1)
    {
        this.appid = appid;
        this.contextid = contextid;
        this.assetid = assetid;
        this.amount = amount;
    }}
```

It is instantiated through:

```
private List<TradeUserAssets> otherOfferedItems;
otherOfferedItems = new List<TradeUserAssets>();
```

But when I use this foreach loop to get the data

```
    foreach (long contextid in Trade.OtherOfferedItems.ToString())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(contextid);
                }
```

The bot crashes. I've tried using a for loop and using the index number after .ToString()[i] like this but I can't get any of the data out. If I do anything other than .ToString() after OtherOfferedItems it won't build. Any help is really appreciated!

EDIT: This is my userHandler.cs

```
    string tradeid;
            if (myItems.Count == 0)
            {
                offer.Accept(out tradeid);
                Log.Success("Accepted trade offer successfully : Trade ID: " + tradeid);

                foreach (asset in Trade.OtherOfferedItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(asset);
                }

                using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=skindump;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;"))
                {
                    var time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
                    var date = DateTime.Now;               

                    date.ToString();

                    connection.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO trades (tradeID, tradeUsed, tradeDate, steamID) VALUES (" + tradeid + ", 1, '" + date + "', '" + OtherSID.ConvertToUInt64() + "');");
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
                    Console.WriteLine(date);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Line 201 is the open squiggly bracket after the mysql connection (var connection = new mysql connection etc...). When I comment out the foreach loop it runs fine without crashing so thats definitely the issue.

Comment: `Trade.OtherOfferedItems` is being referenced as a static variable (or so it would seem).  This doesn't seem to be either compiling or complete code.  There is absolutely no way to reproduce whatever you're experiencing.

Comment: There's more to the instantiation for the TradeUserHandler but I didn't want to paste 800 lines of code. It builds fine, and only crashes when i call the loop. Can someone give some examples of how to access it? Hours of googling isnt working anymore :/

Comment: Without knowing what the structure of "Trade.OtherOfferedItems" is, it's hard to tell why the loop is failing. Can you post more code related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the `contextid` by using `ToString()`, which is the wrong way to do it.

Instead, iterate through the collection of `TradeUserAssets`, and access the property inside the loop.

```
foreach (var asset in Trade.OtherOfferedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(asset.contextid);
}
```

The reason your current code compiles is because it's returning the ascii value for each character in the string that `ToString()` returns (which is just the class name of the collection). Even if it didn't crash the app at runtime, it wouldn't be what you want.

Comment: For both replies I get the same error: 
http://gyazo.com/6f3d4a006b01a8d51bc6a7b64011aaf2
Any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to access a *property* inside of each object of your list. But what you are doing is just converting the `Trade.OtherOfferedItems` list to a string and then looping over that. You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
foreach (TradeUserAssets asset in Tade.OtherOfferedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(asset.contextid);
}
```

Comment: This is what I get when I do that: http://gyazo.com/6f3d4a006b01a8d51bc6a7b64011aaf2

Comment: post your code from the `UserHandler.cs` at line 201 and any instantion of variables in that line.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/3862e6c5e7f022e3527604daf12cf5b4
Yes! Trade is null, now I have to figure out how to fix this. You're awesome Grant!

Comment: `Trade` is null. So you are trying to access its property `OtherOfferedItems` but `Trade` doesn't even exist. So it is not possible that the item collection can exist. You need to take a look at how `Trade` is being created (because, atm, it is not being created)